# Unable to load static files

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-models, django-templates, django-settings

I've added in `settings.py` following:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')
```

in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('^/static/$',
# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

in `models.py`:

```
 class Search(models.Model):
  question = models.URLField()
  query = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

in `views.py`:

```
def home(request):
print ' base dir %s' % BASE_DIR
print ' static dir %s' % STATIC_URL
form = SearchForm()
return render_to_response('base.html', {'form': form},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and `templates/base.html`:

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
            <head>
                <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
                <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <title>Walker</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                <form name="query">
                {{ form.as_p }}
                </form>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                            </div>
            </body>
```

I ran `./manage.py collectstatic` with no porblems, folder `static` being created.

When I execute `./manage.py runserver` I can see in terminal this error:
    base dir home/my/code/walker
    static dir  /static/

```
"GET /static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1691
```

Template loading correctly. But bootstrap do not

Several hour can noot figure out what I need to do

Comment: Is DEBUG set to True?

Comment: @micgeronimo what is the layout of your generated/collected static folder? Does it match `STATIC_ROOT/bootstrap....` ?

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store static files in locations other than `app/static` I think you need to specify `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your `settings.py` otherwise they will not be collected:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "/path/to/static", #collectstatic will find any app/static directories so do not add those here
)
```

By [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) it is empty.

Additionally, specify static files using `href="{% static 'my-static.css' %}"` instead of `{{ STATIC_URL }}`

You can also use [findstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-findstatic) to check if your static files are able to be located by the server.